# how to get more then 20 results from google places api in android

Tags: android, google-places

I'm implemented google places api in an application. But it is returning only  20 results.
Checked the other answers posted, from there I came to know that we need to implement pagination for that one.
Please provide some solution.

Here I'm attaching the code

```
public ArrayList<Place> findPlaces(double latitude, double longitude,
        String placeSpacification) {

    ArrayList<Place> arrayList;
    String urlString = makeUrl(latitude, longitude, placeSpacification);
    System.out.println("url------"+urlString);

    try {
        String json = getJSON(urlString);

        System.out.println(json);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Place>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            try {
                Place place = Place
                        .jsonToPontoReferencia((JSONObject) array.get(i));
                Log.v("Places Services ", "" + place);
                arrayList.add(place);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return arrayList;
    } catch (JSONException ex) {

    }
    return null;
}

    private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String place) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

    if (place.equals("")) {
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        //urlString.append("&radius=2000");
         urlString.append("&types="+place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    } else {
        //urlString.append("rankby=2000&location=");
        urlString.append("&location=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
        urlString.append("&radius=2000");
        urlString.append("&types=" + place);
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    }

    return urlString.toString();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure how google places does it, but most of the time, supplying `offset` and `limit` does what you want. Try adding `&limit=50` and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think there is no keyword like limit in google places api

Comment: can you please provide me full url. where to use exactly this limit

Comment: Does the response contain metadata? For example, one service I use includes such json object in response: `"meta": {
"limit": 20,
"next": "url/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json",
"offset": 0,
"previous": null,
"total_count": 66
},`